# Pass/Fail size test with wget

Tags: testing, wget, filesize

I am running a Docker Container that frequently fails after a restart. On rare occasions the database has an issue that causes it to not work properly, but most of the time restarting the container fixes it.

The container `nightscout/cgm-remote-monitor:latest` cannot autoheal with a Healthcheck because the Kill command does not seem to work properly on it. It also does not contain the `curl` binaries. when it fails to load the wget of localhost:1337 returns a small 2KB file, but when it works it returns a larger 42KB file.

I am currently running a Healthcheck with a `wget` & a `grep` searching for a word, 'Bolus', that does not appear on the failure page but does on a success, but I would rather it test against the size of the page, say fail if the size is less than 10KB, since I believe that will be a more consistent test as the 'Bolus' text might not be there depending on settings.

my current healtchcheck is

```yaml
services:
  nightscout-app:
    image: nightscout/cgm-remote-monitor:latest
    container_name: nightscout
    depends_on:
      - nightscout-mongodb
    user: 1000:1000
    environment:
      - PUID=1000 #optional
      - PGID=1000 #optional
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    volumes:
      - /docker/log/var/log:/var/log:rw
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "wget -q http://localhost:1337 -O - | grep 'Bolus' || (kill -s 15 1 && sleep 10 && kill -s 9 1)"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 20s
```

Currently the `Kill` command doesn't work in the container so I'm using `willfarrell/autoheal` to do the restart, but I have left the kill command in the test-fail anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `--spider` option of GNU `wget` to send `HEAD` request, which will reveal if resource is available under given URL, its' type and its' size, consider following example

```
wget --spider http://www.example.com
```

does write to *stderr*

```
Spider mode enabled.
Check if remote file exists.
--2023-02-23 13:00:20--  http://www.example.com/
Resolving www.example.com (www.example.com)... 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946, 93.184.216.34
Connecting to www.example.com (www.example.com)|2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 648 [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
```

As you might find from it, it does exist, is HTML document, has size (length) of 648. Keep in mind that this is written to *stderr*, if you wish for it to appear at *stdout* you might do

```
wget --spider http://www.example.com 2>&1
```

then use any tool you are allowed to use to get length, for example if GNU AWK is permitted then I could print length itself following way

```
wget --spider http://www.example.com 2>&1 | awk '$1=="Length:"{print $2}'
```

does output

```
648
```

Comment: Thanks that gives me somewhere to start at the very least. I'll still need to make it pass/fail but I assume I'll be able to do something along the lines of an if length>10000 or something like that.

Comment: @LostOnTheLine if you are interested in controlling exit status code of GNU AWK command, then take look at [Exit Statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html)

Comment: For the healthcheck returning anything is a pass. For example the one used returns like 10 lines that have the word `Bolus` in them. If the failure page comes up where it has none *nothing* is returned, so it's a failure. If it returns `42973` it will pass, if it returns `2022` it will also pass. If it returns with an `exit code` that will also pass. What I need is a `null` response if it is less than 10000

Comment: Please consider using `--method=HEAD` instead of `--spider` for this use case.